# How to check if each form control changed their value in reactive forms?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

What I want to achieve in the end is to see which form controls individually from my form have changed and to create a new object with them assigning a boolean of true if they were changed or false if not. Please see below what I achieved so far, but I don't think this the right approach as when I'll have more from controls my method will become gigantic. If you guys have any idea how I can approach this I would really appreciate it.

my Html

```
<form [formGroup]="editProfileForm">
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-input
            *ngIf="profileData"
            formControlName="firstName"
            placeholder="First Name"
          ></ion-input>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>

      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-input
            *ngIf="profileData"
            formControlName="lastName"
            placeholder="Last Name"
          ></ion-input>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
</form>

<ion-fab
    vertical="bottom"
    horizontal="center"
    slot="fixed"
    (click)="onSubmitEditedProfile()">
    <ion-fab-button>
      <ion-icon name="checkmark-outline"></ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button>
</ion-fab>
```

my TS

```
  onSubmitEditedProfile() {
    if (this.profileData !== null) {
      let updatedFirstName = this.editProfileForm.get("firstName").value;
      if (this.profileData.firstname !== updatedFirstName) {
      }
      console.log("it's the same");
    } else {
      console.log("it's different")
  }
```

And as my approach means, I'll do the same for `lastName` and so on

Comment: Yeah... but what do you *really* need? Every form control already has a state available to see if it was messed with (dirty).. so why do you want to add another prop for that..?

Comment: I am sorry if I am not very clear, I want to check every form control if it was changed and in the end, when I send the data to backend I want to send an object with the values of the form control and together with it an object with the same key values assigning true if the value has changed and false if not so when the backend updates the value to run code only on the ones that have been updated. You mentioned dirty, can I do it and check every form control? I've tried but it returns true or false for overall if the form has been changed or not, and not for each form control

Comment: You can check every control in your submitHandler basically by looping through form.controls (so don’t use form.values) - and create the exact custom object you want to sent to the server.

Comment: @Alexandra I got your question submitting a fix shortly hold on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the example where you can iterate each form control and identify either its changed or not based on that populate new array of object.

```
  onSubmitEditedProfile() {
   const formValue = [];
   // iterate over form controls no matter how many control you have.
   Object.keys(this.form.controls).map((key) => {
     // create a new parsed object 
     const parsedValue = {
      [key]: this.form.get(key).value, // key is the actual form control name
      changed: this.form.get(key).dirty // added changed key to identify value change
     }

    // push each parsed control to formValue array.
    formValue.push(parsedValue)
  })

  console.log(formValue)
 }
```

Here is the stackblitz working [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-czrbzk?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Hope this address your requirements.

Comment: dirty property has one cons is if you change value & make it again previous then it would mark it as changed but in real value of that control does not change.
Ex. value is 'karan' one change it to 'karans' & then change back to 'karan' then it shows as changed but actual value is still same

Answer (score 0):

All you need is just to read dirty value on FormGroup or individual FormControl

https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#dirty

```
  onSubmitEditedProfile() {
    if (!this.editProfileForm.dirty) {
      console.log("it's the same");
    } else {
      console.log("it's different")
  }
```

Comment: Be aware, this indicates the value has been changed, but not that is different from the original value. I.e. if you change the value, then change it back, `dirty` is still `true`.